# Redirecting to another page

Tags: php

```
class Redirect {

    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function to($key, $page) {
        if(isset($page) && !empty($page)) {
            header('Location: ?' . $key . '=' . $page);
            exit();
        }
    }

}
```

With this class I can use this:

```
$foo->redirect('page', 'home');
```

instead of this:

```
header('Location: ?page=home);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, for starters, your redirect will never work if you pass in both `$key` and `$page`, as you're asking for the following:

```
1. is not isset($page)
2. is not empty($page)
```

Which means that the redirect will happen only when `$page` is *NOT* **set** *and* *NOT* **empty**. Because [empty() calls isset() internally](https://www.php.net/empty#refsect1-function.empty-notes), you should only need this:

```
if(!empty($page))
```

Additionally, you're not managing your buffers. Ideally, you should use the `ob_` functions as well as `headers_sent()` to check if headers have already been sent. If you don't manage your buffer, you're very likely to hit the infamous "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent" error. [This post goes into further detail on how to fix that error, especially using the `ob_` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php).

Aside from all that, your construct is doing nothing. If your Redirect class only has the `to()` method, perhaps you're better off making it a standalone function, or adding additional functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your time, the isset was a mistake by me. And I did't know about the ob_ functions. I will look into it! Again many thanks!

Comment: Certainly! They are quite powerful in buffering your output.